# How can one find $f(x)$ satisfying $\int_0^1(4x^3-f(x))f(x)dx=\frac47$ without guessing?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$f(x)=2x^3$ satisfies the given equation - it was found by wild guess.

1. Is there any proper method?
2. Are there only finitely many such functions, or infinitely many? (My intuition says there are infinitely many.)

Comment: To answer the 2nd question, one must know from which class of functions $f$ comes from. Is it smooth?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo A question based on this appeared in one of our tests - no nothing about smoothness (differentiability) has been given. The question asked to find the area bounded by x-axis, f(x), x=1 and x=2 - if there's anything useful there?

Comment: Pick an $a \in [0,1]$. Define $$\tilde{f} (x) := \begin{cases} 2 x^3 & \text{ if } x \in [0,1] \setminus \{a\}\\ 1 & \,\text{if } x = a\end{cases}$$ Is it still a solution?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo As this was a MCQ question, meseems that the most appropriate answer is $2x^3$ (as that leads to the correct answer). But in reality, as you have shown, there are infinite solutions. Perhaps, you should write an answer.

Answer (score 11):

We can write it as $$\int_0^1\bigg(4x^3-f(x)\bigg)f(x)dx=\frac47 = \int^{1}_{0}4x^6dx$$

because $$\displaystyle \int^{1}_{0}4x^6dx = \frac{4}{7}x^7\Bigg|_{0}^{1} = \frac{4}{7}$$

So we get $$\int^{1}_{0}\bigg[(f(x))^2-4x^3\cdot f(x)+4x^6\bigg]dx=0$$

So $$\int^{1}_{0}\bigg(f(x)-2x^3\bigg)^2dx = 0\Rightarrow f(x)-2x^3=0\Rightarrow f(x) = 2x^3$$

Comment: of course, the conclusion $f(x)-2x^3=0$ need only hold almost everywhere.

Comment: Forgive me if this is a stupid question but, could you not have a function that behaves like $2x^3$ on $[0,1]$ and otherwise elsewhere?

Comment: That answers the first part of the question. Any idea for the second part?

Comment: @gowrath Your idea seems to confirm that there are infinite functions. Anyone more experienced would like to comment?

Answer (score 3):

**Another way**

Using

$$(a+b)^2 \geq 4ab\Rightarrow ab \leq \frac{(a+b)^2}{4}$$

and equality hold when $a = b.$

Put $a = 4x^3-f(x)$ and $b=f(x)$

$$\bigg(4x^3-f(x)\bigg)f(x)\leq \frac{1}{4}\bigg(4x^3-f(x)+f(x)\bigg)^2$$

$$\int^{1}_{0}\bigg(4x^3-f(x)\bigg)f(x)\leq \frac{1}{4}\int^{1}_{0}\bigg(4x^3-f(x)+f(x)\bigg)^2 = \frac{4}{7}$$

and equality hold when $$4x^3-f(x) = f(x)\Rightarrow f(x) = 2x^3$$

Comment: $4ab\leq(a+b)^2$ is equivalent to $(a-b)^2\geq 0$ which you already use implcitly in the other solution to infer that a certain integrand equals 0 almost everywhere. This solution is redundant.

Comment: @yurnero I would argue that this answer is more natural than the first one.