# Find $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$ without knowing $f(x)$

Tags: calculus

Question:
Let
$$\int_{0}^{1} (2x^2-3f(x))f(x)dx=\frac{1}{15}$$

then find $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$.

I tried applying by parts in it. But was not successful in finding $f(x)$ from there. Is there any way of directly finding $f(x)$ or can we only determine its integral from $0$ to $1$. How should I proceed further?

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3902825/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2071249/42969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
    \int_0^1 [2x^2 - 3f(x)]f(x)dx &= -3\int_0^1 \left[f^2(x) - 2\dfrac{x^2}{3}f(x) + \dfrac{x^4}{9}\right]dx + \dfrac{1}{3}\int_0^1 x^4 dx\\
&= -3 \int_0^1 \left[f(x) - \dfrac{x^2}{3}\right]^2dx + \dfrac{1}{15}  
\end{align*}

Thus,
$$
     \int_0^1 [2x^2 - 3f(x)]f(x)dx = \dfrac{1}{15} \Longleftrightarrow f(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{3}
$$
Therefore,
$$
    \int_0^1 f(x)dx = \dfrac{1}{3}\int_0^1 x^2 dx = \dfrac{1}{9}
$$

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{3}$ (Lebesgue) almost everywhere on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 4):

Note:

$$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt3}x^2\right)^2dx=\frac{1}{15}$$

Then we can complete square:

$$\int_0^1 \left(\sqrt3 f(x)-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}x^2\right)^2dx=0$$

therefore,

$$f(x)=\frac{1}3x^2$$

and

$$\int_0^1f(x)dx=\frac{1}9$$

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{3}$ (Lebesgue) almost everywhere on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, thank you.